# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: this.filters is not a function ? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My component code is like this :

```
<script>
    import _ from 'lodash'
    export default{
        props:['search','category'],
        data(){
            return{
                price_min:'',
                price_max:''
            }
        },
        computed:{
            filters(data){
                const price = {min:this.price_min, max:this.price_max}
                return {q:this.search, category:this.category, sort:data, location:data, price}
            },
        },
        methods:{
            filterProduct: _.debounce(function(data=null){
                    this.$store.dispatch('getProducts', this.filters(data))
            },500)
        }
    }
</script>
```

My full code is like this : http://pastebin.com/K7vwU0yY

When executed, on the console exist error like this :

> Uncaught TypeError: this.filters is not a function

How can I solve the error?

Comment: I think you should declare in the following way: `filters:function(data){...}`.

Comment: computed creates a data property, it is not meant to be used as a function. More like a data property which gets computed with respect to some other variables.

Comment: `location:data, price` what does this line mean? So that I can suggest you an alternative.

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, It's the same. It does not work

Comment: @Amresh Venugopal, See my full code

Answer (score 2):

```
    computed:{
        filters(data) { // the first argument is supposed to be the `this` 
            const price = {min:this.price_min, max:this.price_max}
            return {q:this.search, category:this.category, sort:data, location:data, price}
        },
    },
    methods:{
        filterProduct (data = null) {
           return _.debounce(function (data=null) => {
             this.$store.dispatch('getProducts', this.filters(data))
           },500).call(this, data)
        } 
    }
```

You have lost context to the vue component instance by using an anonymous function. <s>Use an arrow function or save the context in a `let self = this`</s>

In your case, you are returning a function by using `_.debounce(fn() {}, ms)` but doing so, you lost the context to `this`.

So I moved your debounce code inside a method which `.call`s the function callback returned by debounce with `this` set to `vue component` instance.

Moreover `computed` properties are not to be used as function. `this.filters(data)` therefore will still give the similar error as it is a property, just like the ones you can create in `data` of your vue component instance. Use a method instead.

Comment: It make new error. The error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined`

Comment: If you `console.log(this)` before the error, I think you will see a lodash instance. You need to save the variable as `let self = this` and use self throughout the code.

Comment: What is the value of `this` if you console above your dispatch

Comment: @mosestoh the latest edit should work fine. It was not getting the right `this` context.

Comment: It still the error on the console.If you have tried it?

Comment: remove `this.$store.dispatch('getProducts', this.filters(data))` and console.log these lines `console.log(this)` and `console.log(this.$store)`

Comment: It seems `this` is set to the vue instance but `this.$store` is undefined, and hence dispatch is being called on undefined. Please check your vuex store. `Vue.use(vuex)` seems to be missing.